# Relation between regression coefficient and correlation coefficient

Tags: regression, correlation, generalized-linear-model, linear-model, regression-coefficients

For simple linear regression, the regression coefficient's sign and the correlation coefficient's (between independent and dependent variable) sign should be matching or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in the case of a *simple* linear regression, they should be matching! If $x$ increases and $y$ increases, that means they are positively correlated. In that case, the slope (coefficient of $x$) will be positive. If $x$ increases and $y$ decreases, we always have a negative correlation and a negative slope. Also $cor(y,x) = \sqrt{R^2}$.

Comment: If it's not matching, then what could be the reason? Can collinearity couse the issue?

Comment: When you said *simple* linear regression, I assumed you meant with only one independent variable. In that case, it should always match. If it's multiple independent variables, then no, it really doesn't have to match. A correlation is a measure of the linear relationship between 2 variables, while a multiple regression is a measure of the linear relationship between $y$ and multiple $x$s.

Comment: But the coefficient for a variable should be independent of the other variables, since its the change in outcome with a unit increase in the value of that particular variable.  Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: It is not independent. Say you regress $y$ on $x_1$ and $x_2$, and you get significant coefficients $\hat{\beta_1}$ and $\hat{\beta_2}$. Now repeat by omitting $x_2$. Now you have $\hat{\beta_1'}$, which is equal to $\hat{\beta_1}$ plus some bias. The bias is proportional to the correlation between $x_1$ and $x_2$, so the coefficient is *not* independent of the other variables (to be more precise, the variables are not independent of each other). In any case, none of these are applicable in a *simple* linear regression setting, was asked in the original question.

Comment: This is not correct.  The correlation is proportional to the slope and if the slope is negative so is the corrrealtion.

Comment: So how is what I wrote not correct? The sign of the correlation and the sign of the coefficient match.

Comment: This answer is good, but the final formula is incorrect because $\sqrt{R^2}=|R| \ge 0$ whereas the correlation can be negative.